# set selected text of combobox in javascript with some JSTL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jstl, el

i would like to set the selected Text (not value) of a combobox at loading page if a request variable is set.
My attribute name is 'modified' so i try something like this :

javascript :

```
function selection(sel, text) {
if(text != '' || text != null || typeof(text) != 'undefined' ) {
    sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].innerHTML = text;
}
```

in my html :

```
<c:if test="${modified == 1}">
    <DIV class="modified">Group : ${groupe} was modified.
    <script>
    selection(combobox, ${groupe});
    </script>
    </DIV>
</c:if>
```

`<c:..>` tag is from spring-mvc and my div print out nicely

I'm not sure i can access to my EL into some javascript.

i can use both js and jquery.

The end point is to retrieve the selected combobox text, after i submit a form to pre-select the same combobox with the last selectedText (dunno if i'm enough clear)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${groupe}` will just output the content of your variable, so you will end up with something like:

```
selection(combobox, content of your variable);
```

But you need:

```
selection(combobox, "content of your variable");
```

So just add quotes and escape the content (it might contain quotes) using `<c:out>`:

```
selection(combobox, "<c:out value="${groupe}"/>");
```